# What is the "rm" process in Activity Monitor

Tags: activity-monitor, macos, apfs

The `rm` terminal command is being invoked (by an app, not through terminal), and the process has been running for a while at 100%.

Here it is in Activity Monitor:

[image]

Why is it seemingly stuck working so hard? Is there a way to see if it is logging any errors?

I have been having this issue with `rm` ever since upgrading to APFS with 10.13 High Sierra. I just installed VMWare Fusion, so previous issues with `rm` were due to something else.

Comment: Maybe it *is* the terminal command? Check to see if the full command path is shown with `ps -e 1904`

Comment: @DanFrei I updated the question with the results.

Comment: yeah, that is the terminal command.

Comment: Please, type `ps -elxww 1904` and insert output in your OQ.

Comment: Look at `/usr/bin/sudo opensnoop -p 1904`.